# Reshaping matrix with sliding steps

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

Suppose i have a matrix that describes time series data, like this:

[image]

Each column represents an instant (second) in time series, and each row is a sample. I already implemented a function in python that splits each series in a way that i can have more samples like this:

[image]

However, i can generate even more samples if i create a window with fixed size and "slide" through samples:

Supposing `sample_size=2` and `step=1`, the original matrix would generate the following output:

[image]

Any examples on how this could be achieved are very welcome, because i will need to adapt it to a more complex problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `numpy>=1.20`, go with:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view                                                                                                                                                                              

window = sliding_window_view(arr, window_shape=2)
```

Otherwise, it's a bit more elaborated:

```
def rolling(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

window = rolling(arr, 2)
```

Lastly, for simplicity and depending on your use case, consider using `pandas`, for instance:

```
pd.Series(arr.ravel()).rolling(2).apply(some_function)
```

Comment: Thanks, i just need to check if i can update numpy safely since i'm using 1.19.x along with other libraries (pandas, sklearn, etc)